# Calling from android app and permission check

Tags: android, exception, android-adapter, classcastexception

I have an adapter which has an image button. And `OnClick` on `ImageButton` i want to call on the contact number i am parsing. Here its asking me to add permission check. I am getting class cast exception in this stage. Please help.

This is my code:

```
  holder.call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
              } else {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+storePro.getStoreContact()));
                    callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
                }

            }
        });
```

And the exception i am getting:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.project.app.AppController cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the permission in the manifest file? Is there any reason you need to have the permission request on the fly?

Comment: Try using `ContextCompat.requestPermission()` instead of `ActivityCompat.requestPermission()`

Comment: @hildegard FYI you need to handle certain permissions at runtime for android 6.0 and above.

Comment: @Jai only using context asks me to use activity as a first argument and tells me to cast to activity

Comment: @hildegard Marshmallow needs permission check in manifest as well as run time

Comment: @SripadRaj let me check with the ContextCompat.requestPermission().

Comment: @SripadRaj can not resolve ContextCompat.requestPermission()

Comment: The better approach is to define this permission check stuff into one method in your activity and while clicking this button you should call interface to access the same.

Comment: @Jai will try that too. Thanks

Comment: Or pass "this" in constructor of your adapter and create object Activity mActivity and assign as reference and use it directly instead of casting context to activity

Comment: @Jai that gave a null pointer exception. And creating a method inside activity using it in adapter also didnt help

Comment: Check permissions when app starts not in particular onClick. This is better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this code

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {


                        // Should we show an explanation?
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity.this,
                                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

                            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                        } else {

                            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                    2);


                        }
                    }
                    else {
                       // do what you want

                   }
```

Comment: Didnt work. I have this code in adapter. What argument should i be passing for `ActivityName.this` in an adapter??

Comment: your activity name ..like by default it will be MainActivity....So that code will be MainActivity.this it will give you the context of that activity.say whats the result after that...

Comment: Writing the `activityname.this` says not an enclosing class

Comment: what is your Activity name ??

Comment: if you are calling it from different class like adapter ,then there u have to create a constructor and call that Activity context there...

Comment: Finally got it worked. Calling the activity context inside constructor worked :)

Comment: ha ha cool :) and if my answer was helpful pls make it as right.

Comment: Please do few modification in ur answer. Remove `activityname.this` and Add `activity`. Then i can mark it as right

Comment: ok i did.. but you can use your activityname also .. it will take less space in your memory .

Comment: I meant remove whole `activityname.this` and replace it with only `activity`

Answer (score 0):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.project.app.AppController cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

This means you have passed wrong value of the **context** to the Adapter. You should pass an activity context to it.

Comment: Ya i know i have passed a context. But i am supposed to check this permission in an adapter. When i am trying to pass an activity its throwing null pointer exception

Comment: How to pass an activity context??

Comment: @varuni could you show me how you init your adapter and pass the context?

Comment: Like this --> `new StoreProfileRecycle(storeProfileAdapters,getActivity().getApplicationContext());`

Comment: And constructor of my adapter--> `public StoreProfileRecycle(List<StoreProfileAdapter> storeProfile, Context context) {
        super();
        this.storeProfile = storeProfile;
        this.context = context;
    }`

Comment: try this `new StoreProfileRecycle(storeProfileAdapters,getActivity());`

Comment: But what will be argument for requestPermission method?

Comment: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);`

Comment: Finally got it worked. Calling the activity context inside constructor worked :) And the argument will just the activity variable thats passed in the constructor

Comment: Ok, so the problem is just as I answered above, the **context** is wrong